# How to disable Autologon enabled by using Sysinternal's Autologon.exe?

Tags: command-line, auto-login

I have enabled autologon in about 150 machines (all in domain) using batch file which uses Sysinternal's Autologon.exe and PSEXEC.exe program. Now I want to disable that in all machines. But It seems like autologon.exe doesn't have a "Disable" option in command line mode. How can I disable autoLogon enabled by AutoLogon.exe through command Line?

Answer (score 1):

The program autologon.exe itself cannot disable this. However, all autologon.exe does is change some things in the registry. Because of this you could write a script to get rid of these registry settings to run from the command prompt.
You would have to edit the sections in this set of entries: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

I know this is the opposite of what you are looking for but use this question for help: [How do I change automatic logon via Script or Command Line?](https://superuser.com/questions/340396/how-do-i-change-automatic-logon-via-script-or-command-line)

Comment: I already tried this.. But the AutoLogon.exe will store the password somewhere in registry. Not in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon. Correct ? Could you plz tell me that password key path ?

Comment: indeed, autologon.exe "" "" "" will disable the autologin again.

Comment: Hmm, autologon.exe "" "" "" didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the logon password out of the registry from a remote computer will not be possible according to this: https://keithga.wordpress.com/2013/12/19/sysinternals-autologon-and-securely-encrypting-passwords/

I don't know if it is possible to write a script and run it locally as admin, because a 'reg query' command in an administrative prompt gives an Access Denied.

However you can disable the autologon in the registry in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon by setting AutoAdminLogon to 0 and removing AutoLogonSID

Answer (score 1):

This answer contains some new info, so read it to the end.
This application can't disable autologon by just command line, but you can do it with a script, that do exactly the app does (if app's GUI is used for autologon disabling). The app just deletes values `DefaultDomainName`, `DefaultPassword`, and `DefaultUserName` from `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` registry key, and sets `AutoAdminLogon` value to `0`. The app doesn't delete logon password, which stored at LSA secrets, because the password is securely encrypted anyway. But you can delete it, though. It stored at `HKLM\SECURITY\Policy\Secrets\DefaultPassword` subkeys' default values, so you can delete mentioned key. You must act as SYSTEM for this operation, because that key is protected from users, even administrators.

Comment: @FleetCommand If one stores the AutoAdminLogon DefaultPassword in LSA it is in fact 
encrypted and saved under `HKLM\SECURITY\Policy\Secrets\DefaultPassword` and can be decrypted. In this case it's not just a password hash being stored on the system.

Comment: @megamorf Do you have a source attesting to that too?

Comment: @FleetCommand https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/07/06/use-powershell-to-decrypt-lsa-secrets-from-the-registry/

Comment: @megamorf I don't know. That article and its script puzzles me to no end and it doesn't help its script doesn't run on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of green's answer, I was able to successfully remove the autologon by calling this script, located on a shared folder, from the command line:

```
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultDomainName /y
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultPassword /y
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultUserName /y
```

The extra argument at the end bypasses the need to confirm each line.

Answer (score 0):

Autologon by  Windows Sysinternals needs to be disabled on each machine individually by running the .exe

Answer (score -2):

According to the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905.aspx), you should be able to run Autologon.exe again and just hit the "Disable" button. If this is Windows XP, you can try [this Microsoft FixIt](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231) or the instructions on that site. You could probably also just create a registry file which will delete those keys for you (maybe it's even contained in the FixIt file).

Comment: He specifically specified command line mode. No buttons.