# Disable login password option in powershell or cmdline

Tags: passwords

Is there any way to disable the login entering password option by powershell or cmdline instead of doing it in netplwiz gui.
I ran this script though it said successful but it does not make any change.
wmic useraccount where name='username' set PasswordRequired=False

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change automatic logon via Script or Command Line?](https://superuser.com/questions/340396/how-do-i-change-automatic-logon-via-script-or-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

The dialog in your question does dual functions : It enables login
without entering a password, but also sets up the selected user
for auto-login.

In other words, you always need a password, but you can set up
Windows to automatically log you in with your selected
user name and password, thus by-passing the login screen.

For details about setting the login user via the command line,
see the post
[How do I change automatic logon via Script or Command Line?](https://superuser.com/questions/340396/how-do-i-change-automatic-logon-via-script-or-command-line)

Comment: Why the downvote?