# Person with disability logging to Windows 11 Lenovo with touch screen

Tags: windows-11

My sister in law is a handicap. She can use the keyboard but with difficulties, and she cannot speak clearly.
I bought for her [Lenovo with touchscreen](https://www.lenovo.com/ca/en/p/laptops/ideapad/ideapad-flex-series/ideapad-flex-5-gen-8-(14-inch-amd)/82xx0036us?cid=ca:seo:41h72l), with Windows 11.
I was trying to setup the easiest way to login, and I tried to do a face recognition.
But for my frustration, the built-in camera is not compatible with Windows hello face recognition.
The second option was fingerprint, which we setup successfully, and when she use the fingerprint she can login successfully.

But it seems I had to do a PIN, and the PIN is the default login method.
She prefer the fingerprint as a default, and she doesn't prefer every time to choose to switch from PIN to fingerprint.

I couldn't find a way to make the default way is the finger print.

Is there a way to do that?

She uses the computer at her school, so she needs to make it to force her to login after an idle time, and the easiest is to make the default login is the fingerprint.

And another question on the same subject, what other features in windows 11 that make it easy for her to use?
As I said, she can use the keyboard , but not that fast, and she cannot speak clearly.

Comment: Why not setup an auto-login, so nothing is needed ? [link](https://superuser.com/questions/340396/how-do-i-change-automatic-logon-via-script-or-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

To setup the default login method :

- Run the Command Prompt (CMD) or Terminal
- Enter this command : `wmic useraccount get name,sid`
- Note down the SID for the user account
- Close CMD or Terminal
- Run `regedit`
- Navigate to key
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\UserTile`
- On the right locate the user SID and change its value as follows:

  - Password: `{60B78E88-EAD8-445C-9CFD-0B87F74EA6CD}`
  - Microsoft Account: `{F8A0B131-5F68-486C-8040-7E8FC3C85BB6}`
  - PIN: `{D6886603-9D2F-4EB2-B667-1971041FA96B}`
  - **Windows Hello Fingerprint**: `{BEC09223-B018-416D-A0AC-523971B639F5}`
  - Windows Hello Face: `{8AF662BF-65A0-4D0A-A540-A338A999D36F}`
  - Picture Logon: `{2135F72A-90B5-4ED3-A7F1-8BB705AC276A}`
- Close `regedit` and reboot.