# Fast kernel reboot with Windows 10 : how to execute a quick partial reboot with a powershell script?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, kernel

In windows 10, instead of doing a full reboot, it's convenient to do a partial reboot by login out and login in again, for instance to reload a certain set of drivers and OS user related data.
I can do a full reboot with `restart-computer`, but that's not what I want. I am looking for a fast cycle and the effects of a logoff-login cycle (on drivers and userworld in particular).

- Is there a way to achieve this quick reboot by the mean of one powershell script ?
  In particular, I do not want to have to specify again which user (local user) and the password.
- More technically, I know that a few drivers are unloaded and then reloaded in the "logoff-login" cycle; would that be called a fast kernel reboot ?

A certain edition of Windows server (Azure Stack HCI) allows kernel soft reboot (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/manage/kernel-soft-reboot), this is **not** what I am looking for.

Comment: @John Are you sure, as my understanding of Fast Startup is it saves the current state of the system to `hiberfil.sys`, then uncompresses and boots to the system state that was saved to `hiberfil.sys`. Since Fast Startup creates issues when installing programs requiring system state refreshes, such as services needing to be stopped and restarted, is that what the OP is looking for?

Comment: @JW0914 In your nomenclature, 'fast startup' does not do any reboot (unload then reload of any user data and drivers), it just save the current state and then put it back. So no, this is orthogonal.

Comment: The default nature of a system reboot or even a shutdown on Windows 10 and Windows 11 is to utilize the hybrid shtudown to allow for a fast startup.  You have to explicitly disable that behavior to get a full shutdown.  What you want to happen is not clear for that reason. "would that be called a fast kernel reboot?" - No; When you log out of a user and log back into a user the NT kernel isn't restarted.  " I do not want to have to specify again which user (local user) and the password." - There is no way to perform any kind of reboot and expect NOT to reauthenticate the user again.

Comment: @Ramhound The hybernation cycle do not have the effects the logoff-login cycle have. I updated the OP.

Comment: @Soleil - A system reboot should be nearly instantaneous once the Windows is restarted due to hybrid startup on a SSD.

Comment: @Soleil The MS article you posted answers your question "*New in Azure Stack HCI, version 21H2, Kernel Soft Reboot (KSR) is a premium feature available on all Azure Stack HCI integrated systems.*" right there in the sentence up top. This does not apply to Windows 10 and generally with it, a full system reboot is the recommended method to ensure a clean restart of the kernel. You could technically brute force hack it with the autologin as HarryMC explains or sysinternals to save the password more securely, and then post cleanup the tracks, etc.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle As I wrote, I am *not* looking for this but the logoff-login cycle or equivalent, for its consequences.

Comment: I've read about this for Windows Updates effectiveness for doing something that sounds similar but I have never used it or seen it in use myself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/component-updates/winlogon-automatic-restart-sign-on--arso-. I'm sure there's a way to trace out what Windows is doing or setting, etc. with this and see if you can trick it to think it needs to do this for a Windows Update to be effective.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you wish to automatically logoff and then
login back as the same user.
This is impossible in one PowerShell script, as it would be terminated
by the logoff, but there is a trick.

The trick is to set your account to be auto-login and then logout.
You would then be automatically logged back in.

To turn on automatic logon in Windows, see the post
[How do I change automatic logon via Script or Command Line?](https://superuser.com/questions/340396/how-do-i-change-automatic-logon-via-script-or-command-line)
You may set the listed registry entries in your PowerShell script,
before executing the logoff.

For logoff, see the article
[Changing computer state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/changing-computer-state?view=powershell-7.4#logging-off-the-current-session).
The simplest is to execute the command `shutdown.exe -l`.

If you have for login a "welcome message", you will still have
to click on OK to fully log in.

Comment: Interesting, but it poses a security threat. And what about setting the autologin by ps, logoff and login back, and unset autologin ? In that case I won't have the permanent autologin

Comment: You may add a logon script that will delete the autologin registry entries, so they don't stay forever.